# Issues with line join in rgl

Tags: r, 3d, rgl

When using rgl, I am trying to get smooth lines drawn in 3D space. At certain view angles, the lines join smoothly together; at other view angles, they look completely disjointed.

For example, using `3dlines` to draw the following:

```
x = c(-32.76755,-32.84534,-32.90371,-32.94217,-32.96003,-32.95662,-33.04784,-33.03502,-32.98490,-32.86505,-32.79418,-32.59470,-32.52399,-32.44813,-32.23378,-32.18913)
y = c(13.15037,12.38736,11.65954,10.9627,10.29022,9.6338,8.67939,7.70395,7.04928,6.05184,5.37749,4.35355,3.64888,2.92609,1.86025,1.11037)
z = c(1.54869,2.22778,2.94911,3.70456,4.48397,5.27592,5.11489,4.94259,5.70322,5.48567,6.18623,5.90521,6.53304,7.12764,6.74987,7.29049)
```

with a line width of `10`:

```
lines3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, lwd=10)
```

at this angle, it looks ok:

```
par3d(userMatrix = matrix(data = c(0.7643722, -0.0511867, -0.6427402, 0, -0.5819589, 0.3744012, -0.7219055, 0, 0.2775946, 0.9258529, 0.2563933, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
```

[image: Correct line join]

but here, there is an issue with the joining between the lines:

```
par3d(userMatrix = matrix(data = c(0.85497350, -0.02970354, -0.51782036, 0, -0.4698080, 0.3786791, -0.7974223, 0, 0.2197740, 0.9250512, 0.3098056, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1), nrow=4, ncol=4))
```

[image: Incorrect line joins]

Is this just a limitation of rgl, or is there a setting I'm missing here?

Comment: The images look the same, are they?

Comment: @Peter Yes, for some reason the wrong image uploaded; I've corrected it. Thanks for catching that!

Comment: You generally get better results with fat lines using `rglwidget()` to display in the browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is a deeper issue with OpenGL: [OpenGL GL_LINES endpoints not joining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4532342/opengl-gl-lines-endpoints-not-joining/4532365#4532365)

Base-R has a [graphical parameter that adds rounded ends to line segments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74452941/r-plot-function-with-type-h-misrepresents-small-numbers-for-larger-values/74453121#74453121). It doesn't exist for `rgl`, but adding points at the intersection is a (hacky) way to fill in the gaps ...

```r
lines3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, lwd=10)
points3d(x=x, y=y, z=z, size=10, point_antialias = TRUE)
```

`point_antialias = TRUE` is supposed to make points display as circles rather than squares, which would be prettier, but is device-dependent; doesn't have any effect on the machine I'm on at the moment, so if you look closely you can see the corners of the square. Still, I think it's an improvement.

[image]

(I didn't use your exact `par3d()` ...)

Answer (score 1):

As @BenBolker said in his answer, this is an issue with line drawing in the old OpenGL pipeline that `rgl` uses in R.  If you export the scene to WebGL by calling `rglwidget()`, it uses more modern OpenGL shaders, and looks a lot better.

A workaround within R is to draw cylinders instead of lines.  These will be slower to display, but modern graphics hardware is fast enough that you probably won't notice any difference.

For example,

```
line <- cylinder3d(cbind(x, y, z), radius = 0.1)
shade3d(line, col = "black", lit = FALSE)
```

[image: screen shot]

The width varies a little along the line, but I find that less distracting than the breaks at the corners.